# retrieve_password_notification_email hook not working as expected. What can I do?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

i am trying to send the password reset email to a secondary email address saved in usermeta, not the main one used for registration. I'm using the retrieve_password_notification_email hook, but my function seems does not get executed.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_notification_email/

here's my code:

`

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_notification_email','forward_notification_function');

function forward_notification_function($defaults) {
     
     $userID = $defaults['user_data']->get_the_ID();
     $name =  get_user_meta( $userID , 'billing_company', true);
     $notification_email = get_user_meta($userID, 'ima_email', true);
     $defaults['to'] = "TO: ".$name ." ".$userID." <".$notification_email.">\r\n";   
     return $defaults;  
    
}
```

`

I also tried to run a simple wp_mail call using the hook but it does not work for some reason

Comment: Use preferences for the add_filter function, it might have an effect.

Comment: I tried, seems to have no effect 
`add_filter( 'retrieve_password_notification_email','forward_notification_function',10,1);`